# "Please install the "intl" extension for full localization capabilities" when intl IS installed

Tags: php-7, symfony-2.8, php-7.1, intl, php-7.2

Symfony 2.8 project in ubuntu 16.04

I got this exception:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("The
>   Symfony\Component\Intl\DateFormatter\IntlDateFormatter::__construct()
>   method's argument $locale value 'es' behavior is not implemented. Only
>   the locale "en" is supported. Please install the "intl" extension for
>   full localization capabilities.").

Ok, but I have the intl extension already installed:

```
php -i | grep int

/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-intl.ini,
intl
intl.default_locale => no value => no value
intl.error_level => 0 => 0
intl.use_exceptions => 0 => 0
```

Maybe is that default_locale with no value the problem? I have libicu installed too so no idea what is the problem.

It happens with php7.0, php7.1 and php7.2

Comment: This happened to me w/ Symfony 2.8 on Ubuntu 17.10 when I switched from php7 to 7.1 recently. I just installed the current intl extension and restarted the apache. That seemed to work.

apt-get install php7.1-intl

Comment: What's the output of `php -m | grep "intl"`?